# Why do the query result according to descending timestamp in Apache IoTDB cannot be returned?

Tags: performance, cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I stored a large amount of data in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0, and I found a problem recently. When I tried to query this massive amount data by ascending timestamp order, I got the corresponding result quickly, but when I tried to query by descending timestamp order, it tooks very long time and the result cannot be shown. Are there any ways to optimize this progress? Also if can be improved, after compiling the new method, will the existing cluster environment and data now not be affected?

Anyone know that? Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, you can compile it yourself with the latest Version 1.1 code of Apache IoTDB. After compilation, your cluster and data now will NOT be affected. You can directly replace the `lib` folder.